# Rates of Change Question help

Tags: related-rates

I just wanted to check to see if I answered this question correctly :) any help would be much appreciated

**Q.** Air is pumped into a spherical balloon such that the volume of the balloon is increasing at a rate of 3cm^2cm/sec.

(i)Find the rate of change of the radius of the balloon , when the radius is 7cm.Leave your answer in terms of PI.

(ii)Find the rate of change of the surface area of the balloon when the radius is 9cm

**What I did:**

(i) I differentiated the volume of a sphere to get dv/dt= 4πr^2 . I then subbed 7 in for r and the answer I got was 196π.

(ii) I differentiated the surface area of a sphere which gave me an answer of 8πr.I then subbed in 9 for r and I got 72π as my answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.  As to the question, no you're not doing it correctly.  The rate of change of the volume is always $3$, no matter what the radius.  We are given the rate of change as cm$^2$ per second, which means that the independent variable is time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are asked for the rate of change of the radius, that is for $\frac{dr}{dt}$.  We have $$3=\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}$$ using $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}$$

Can you finish it now?

Comment: Wow you're so right!! I completely forgot about that part. Thanks so much for that :)

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark, so that it leaves the unsolved queue.

Comment: The answer I got after following the above method is $1/28 cm_3/sec$

Comment: You should have gotten $\frac3{196\pi}$

Comment: On further calculation , I did indeed get the above answer